# Homotopy section but no pointed homotopy section

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Can anyone give an example of a pointed map $p:(E,e)\to (B,b)$ between connected pointed spaces (reasonably nice, say of the homotopy type of CW complexes) such that $p$ admits a homotopy section but does not admit a pointed homotopy section? That is, there exists a map $s:B\to E$ such that $p\circ s:B\to B$ is freely homotopic to the identity, but there does not exist any pointed map $\sigma:(B,b)\to (E,e)$ such that $p\circ \sigma:(B,b)\to (B,b)$ is pointed homotopic to the identity?

Comment: Let $B$ be the comb space with its bad basepoint, let $E=\ast$, and let $p$ be the inclusion of the basepoint.

Comment: If $p\circ s$ is freely homotopic to the identity then it is a weak homotopy equivalence, and therefore has a pointed homotopy inverse. Precomposing $s$ with this inverse will give you a pointed homotopy section. So it seems to me that what you are asking for is impossible.